# How to get the result for test steps other than test request using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

How to capture a test result details for test steps other than test request(Say Groovy script step) using groovy for soap ui?

For test request we can capture the result based on assertion result but for other test steps how can i get the result?

Comment: Hey, is there is any one who can help?

Answer (score 0):

You must create assertions in the test than you want export the date. You must parse your json, xml, ... and later save the field than you want in a property of this test suite, also you can save in the properties of your project. Example of assertions:

```
**import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("correlationID", jsonSlurper.uuid)**
```

Also you can use:

```
**testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( "correlationID", jsonSlurper.uuid)
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("correlationID", jsonSlurper.uuid)**
**testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("correlationID", jsonSlurper.uuid)**
```

Then you have correlationID in the properties, the properties in this case name properties, of your test case, suite, project, ...

Finally only have than write in the header

```
Name                         Value

**correlationID    '${Properties#correlationID}'**
```